# relation between etcd/zookeeper/consul and other configuration management tools like chef/puppet/..?

Tags: chef-infra, puppet, apache-zookeeper, etcd

Just according my high level understanding, both groups (for eg., etcd and puppet) do distributed configuration management, am I right or wrong?  Or is it that puppet uses etcd internally? If so, an example may help.

Regards,
Seenu.

Answer (score 7):

Although Chef/Puppet and etcd/zookeeper/consul both can be used to build your infrastructure and for service discovering, the services and solution they offer are quite different. They are not confronted solutions and in fact can be used simultaneously, because the services they provide are different.

- The IT automation tools (i.e.: Chef/Pupper/Ansible...) provide a full stack to deploy, provision and manage you infrastructure. They offer solutions to keep information about your architecture (eg.: which machines provide some services), this is only a small piece in the puzzle. This information is updated and used only during the convergence of a node, and not should be used for a very dynamic infrastructure.
- etcd/zookeeper/consul are K/V distributed stores with some differences in implementation and service provided, but very similar in concept. They provide mechanism for service discovery, and fast update of this information. They don't provide a full stack to deploy and configure your infrastructure, although they can be used as part of a stack to achieve this goal, working with other tools (i.e.: confd, consul-template, scripts, or chef/puppet/ansible...). etcd/zookeeper/consul are solutions designed thinking in very dynamic infrastructure and provide an easy interface to keep you services configuration updated in any moment, but you will need other tools to automate all your infrastructure.